# Does MAc Address of a Google Compute Engine changes ever, without deleting the Virtual machine

Tags: google-app-engine

I have created a Virtual machine on Google Compute Engine and I am installing my Application on this Virtual machine.

Licensing of my application is based on the MAC Address of the machine.

So My Question is Does MAC Address of Google Virtual machine gets changed automatically ever??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to this [1] GCE Instance doesn't change MAC address even if the machine is stopped [2]. MAC address will be released when GCE machine deletion is asked.

[1] - https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances

[2] - https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances#stopping_an_instance